# Border width on image in TCPDF

Tags: image, pdf, border, tcpdf

I created an image in `TCPDF` with `$pdf->Image(...` and set the `border value to = 1.`

But how do I change the width of the border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SetLineWidth() method will work.

http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a0ef34c0ce76bd8e4671da42b3588d9b6

I tested this by adjusting the border argument in the Image() call at line 38 of example_003.php to enable the border and then adjusted as follows and observed that the border became thicker:

```
    $this->SetLineWidth( 1 );
    $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 15, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank's.